# Nested observables subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I have the following code:

```
getUsers() {
    this.af.database.list(DB_URL)
    .map((users) => {
      return users.map((user) => {
        user.data = this.af.database.object(DB_URL_2).take(1);
        return user;
      });
    })
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((itemPrefs) => {
      this.users = users;
    })
  }
```

Which returns `users` array, where `user.data` is an observable (the user information).

How I can return the data of the `user` as an object and not as an observable? I tried to subscribe to my `user.data` but it still returning the observable:

```
return users.map((user) => {
            user.data = this.af.database.object(DB_URL_2).take(1)
.subscribe((data) => {
return data;
});
        return user;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `selectMany` should do the trick, each inner function of <strike>`selectMany`(RxJS4)</strike> `mergeMap`(RxJS 5) would to return `observable` that will flatten. Which means that it will make sure that all inner `data` would be flatten.

**Code**

```
getUsers() {
    this.af.database.list(DB_URL)
    .mergeMap((user, i) => {
        return this.af.database.object(DB_URL_2).take(1).map(data => {
           user.data = data;
           return user;
        });
      });
    })
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((itemPrefs) => {
      this.users = users;
    })
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can import the `selectMany` operator in Angualr 2? I tried `import 'rxjs/add/operator/selectMany';`

Comment: @TheUnreal I guess it would be `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`

Comment: `Property 'selectMany' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.`

Comment: @TheUnreal sorry for inconvenience, `selectMany` was used in `rxjs4`, since we are using `RxJS5` it became `mergeMap`. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @TheUnreal could you please confirm that does it work for you or not?

Comment: Thank you but In my first DB CALL I get a list of users, and each user has ` `$key`. when I'm using `user.$key` in the second DB CALL I get `property $key does not exists on type all[]`.

Comment: I did console log it, it turns out that the `user` inside the mergeMap is an array of all the users.

Comment: @TheUnreal the problem was `selectMany` was best way to handle this in `rxjs4`, but `rxjs5` they said that it would be used as `mergeMap` going forward, but it isn't working in that way. Check [migration guide here rxjs4 to rxjs5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md). Will dig deeper into it in sometime